# Thread-safe message queue without mutex in C

Tags: c, thread-safety, queue, circular-list

I'm trying to write a message queue implementation
so my threads can exchange data.
To keep things simple, the queue is only responsible for
sending pointers to memory. Only one thread may send messages,
and only one thread may read messages.

The struct `mq_t` represents a message queue.

- `mq_t.messages` is a circular buffer of pointers.
- `mq_t.send` is the index of the last sent message.
- `mq_t.recv` is the index of the next message to be received.

I'd like to know some things:

1. Thread Safety: I didn't use a mutex or lock, but I think the code is quite thread-safe. Is this true?
2. In the code I use things like `while (isempty(queue));`. Is there a better way to handle such things, like suspending the thread until a memory change occurs?
3. Cross Platform: does my code rely on some non-cross platform code or undefined behaviour?
4. Are there other things wrong with my code (except the highly generic function names)?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define null ((void*)0)
#define SIZE 2

typedef struct {
    int send;
    int recv;
    void * messages[SIZE];
} mq_t;

inline int isfull(mq_t * queue) {
    return (queue->send+1)%SIZE == queue->recv;
}

inline int isempty(mq_t * queue) {
    return queue->send == queue->recv;
}

mq_t * create(void) {
    mq_t * queue = (mq_t*)malloc(sizeof(mq_t));
    queue->send = 0;
    queue->recv = 0;
}

void send(mq_t * queue, void * message) {
    while (isfull(queue));
    int next = (queue->send+1) % SIZE;
    queue->messages[next] = message;
    queue->send = next;
}

void * recv(mq_t * queue) {
    while (isempty(queue));
    void * message = queue->messages[queue->send];
    queue->recv = (queue->recv+1) % SIZE;
    return message;
}

void destroy(mq_t * queue) {
    while (!isempty(queue));
    free(queue);
}
```

**Test:**

```
void * sender(void * queue) {
    send(queue, "hello, ");
    send(queue, "world");
    send(queue, "how are you?");
    printf("sent data\n");
}

void * recver(void * queue) {
    sleep(1);
    printf("received '%s'\n", recv(queue));
    printf("received '%s'\n", recv(queue));
    printf("received '%s'\n", recv(queue));
}

int main() {
    mq_t * queue = create();

    pthread_t s, r;
    pthread_create(&s, null, sender, (void*)queue);
    pthread_create(&r, null, recver, (void*)queue);
    pthread_join(s, null);
    pthread_join(r, null);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> received 'hello, '
> received 'world'
> received 'how are you?'
> sent data
> ```

Comment: I don't think POSIX is portable to windows these days. I'm not very windows-savvy so I could easily be mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a size of 2, your 'queue' can hold only one item, so it is not really a queue.  If
you increase the size to 8 (say) you now really have a queue, but your tests don't
work.

You seem to define `send` and `recv` as follows:

- `send` indicates the 'slot' holding the most recently entered data (queue not empty).
- `recv` indicates the 'slot' **before** the oldest data in the queue (queue not empty).
- if `send == recv`  the queue is empty.

So with both `send` and `recv` at zero, when the first data is written it goes to slot 1 and `send` is incremented to 1; when the 2nd data is written it goes to slot 2 and `send` is incremented to 2.  If you now read from the queue, in `recv` you use the `send` counter to extract the data instead of using `recv + 1`.  Hence the queue fails.

A more logical arrangement might be as follows with the counters renamed `in`
and `out` (naming them the same as the access functions is confusing):

- `in` indicates the next 'slot' to be written by `send` (queue not empty).
- `out` indicates the 'slot' containing the next data to be read by `recv` (queue not empty).
- if `in == out` the queue is empty.

So with both `send` and `recv` at zero, when the first data is sent, it goes into slot 0 (to which `in` and `out` already point) and `in` is incremented to 1.  The first read now reads from `out` at 0 - which is correct.

---

On thread safety, it is very difficult to see/analyse such things.  You would be
better to assume that it isn't (it certainly wouldn't be if there were more
than 2 threads) and use a mutex.  As your wait loops need to be rewritten
(they just waste CPU cycles needlessly) and you are using Posix threads, use a
Posix mutex and a "condition variable" to synchronise.

Here's an example, but there are many more on the web: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-posix3/

---

Some minor coding points:

- Add `const` to pointer parameters that do not change.
- Return a value from `create`
- Don't cast the return from `malloc`.  Casting is necessary in C++ not C
  (where void* can be assigned to any pointer).  In C, adding a cast can cause
  problems if you don't have the header for `malloc` included, as the compiler
  will assume that `malloc` returns an `int`.  If `int` and `pointer` have
  different sizes this is a problem.
- `null` is not really needed.  You can use either 0 or NULL.
- the `_t` type suffix is apparently reserved by Posix.

Answer (score 0):

This code is surely not MTsafe:

```
void send(mq_t * queue, void * message) {
    while (isfull(queue));
    int next = (queue->send+1) % SIZE;
```

After `while (isfull(queue));` and before `queue->send = next;`, you can enter a bit of threads and writes in common slot before they update `queue->send` pointer that cause `isfull` to locked state.